# Rails creates excess child record when saving with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my models:

```
class PaymentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_payment_profiles, inverse_of: :payment_profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_payment_profiles
end

class UserPaymentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :payment_profile, inverse_of: :user_payment_profiles
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_payment_profiles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :payment_profiles, through: :user_payment_profiles, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In my controller:

```
class PaymentProfilesController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :json
  before_action :find_user

  def create
    @payment_profile = @user.payment_profiles.build(payment_profile_params)
    @payment_profile.creator_id = params[:user_id]
    @payment_profile.save
    respond_with @payment_profile
  end

  private

    def find_user
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end
end
```

Im creating new PaymentProfile and UserPaymentProfile records through json by using accepts_nested_attributes_for

```
i.e POST /users/1/payment_profiles

{"payment_profile": {"amount":"200", "user_payment_profiles_attributes": [ {"user_id": "2"}, {"user_id": "3"} ]}}
```

so params in PaymentProfilesController :create action are

```
{"payment_profile"=>{"amount"=>"200", "user_payment_profiles_attributes"=>[{"user_id"=>"2"}, {"user_id"=>"3"}]}, "user_id"=>"1"}
```

But instead of creating 2 UserPaymentProfile instances, Rails is creating 3! Using that "user_id"=>"1" from params hash that is coming from the url /users/1/payment_profiles

How can the problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault,
it should be

```
@payment_profile = PaymentProfile.new(payment_profile_params)
```

instead of

```
@payment_profile = @user.payment_profiles.build(payment_profile_params)
```

rails was creating join model automatically